# Returning an intersection set of two vectors from a function

Tags: c++, vector

Can somebody help me please, why cant I seem to get the intersection set  when I later print out the resulting vector out_v in a seperate function ? I don't know what is wrong, I am passing the vectors using pointers to the function below Array* operator+ (Array* inp_v) which should later Return a pointer to a resulting vector from set_intersection. Could it be that my set_intersection is not working or is it somtheing else?
I have included all stl headers neccesery.

```
Array* operator+ (Array* inp_v)
{

    XorArray *v1 = (XorArray *)inp_v;
    XorArray *out_v = new XorArray();
    vector<double>::iterator iVect1 = v1->vect.begin();
    vector<double>::iterator iVect2 = this->vect.begin();

    vector<double> Result;

    sort(iVect1, v1->vect.end());
    sort(iVect2, this->vect.end());

    vector<double>::iterator newEnd = set_intersection(iVect1,      v1>vect.end(), iVect2, this->vect.end(),Result.begin());

    while (newEnd != Result.end()
     {
        out_v->vect.push_back(*newEnd);
        ++newEnd;
    }                                           

    return out_v;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A major problem is that the `result` vector is *empty*, which means that `result.begin() == result.end()`. To append new items in the `result` vector you need to use e.g [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter).

I suggest you check a [`std::set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) reference.

Comment: I finally figured it out thaks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Use a back_inserter to push stuff into the result container. For example, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection